# Set new date 12 months after in a form

Tags: javascript, date

I am very new to script and checked many answers but could not find the complete answer. 
In a form, I have a start date, number of months and end date - I want to display the end date when the start date is entered - I have created this script but I must be missing something.

Here's my code:

```
[script type="text/javascript" src=Datejs][/js]
[script type="text/javascript" ]
    window.onload = function() {
        var startdateEl = document.getElementById("customFields_cf_232");
        var leasetermEl = document.getElementById("customFields_cf_34");
        var enddateEl = document.getElementById("customFields_cf_38");
        function CalculateDate {
            var enddateEl=leasetermEl.months().startdateEl;  
        }
        var enddateEl.onblur = CalculateDate;
    };
[/script]
```

Comment: What is the valid format of a date you can type into input?

Answer (score 0):

I made this. It listens to your keystrokes live. http://jsfiddle.net/4t54J/

```html
<input name="startDate" type="text" value="MM-DD-YYYY" />
<input name="endDate" type="text" />
```

```js
var SECOND = 1000;
var MINUTE = SECOND * 60;
var HOUR = MINUTE * 60;
var DAY = HOUR * 24;
var YEAR = DAY * 365.25;

var startDateInput = 'input[name="startDate"]';
var endDateInput = 'input[name="endDate"]';

$(startDateInput).live('keypress', function (e) {
    var startDate = $(startDateInput).val();
    var endDate = setEndDate(startDate);
    $(endDateInput).val(endDate);
});

function setEndDate(startDate) {
    var date = new Date();
    var parts = startDate.split('-');
    if (date != '' && parts.length > 2) {
        // year, month (0-based), day
        date.setFullYear(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parts[1]);
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + YEAR);
        var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
        mm = (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm.toString();
        var dd = date.getDate();
        var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
        return mm + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```